# How to keep scrollbar from automatically going back to the top?

Tags: scrollbars

I have a list of links within a div with a scrollbar. When the user clicks on a link below the x-height of the div, the srollbar automatically goes back to the top. I would like the scrollbar to stay in position no matter what links the user clicks. [Here is the site](http://siddharthparasnis.com/)- try clicking on a painting from 2006 and you'll see what I mean.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can make this scrollbar behave?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these links are just that, links to a new page... and thus it's not so much that the scrollbar is resetting but that a whole brand new page is coming up and the 'reset' scrollbar is just a byproduct.

The most elegant way would be to have those links pull in the new content without reloading the page, but this requires AJAX. If you aren't familiar with the intricacies of AJAX and how to implement that, then you could change the link to include an anchor to the link, like so:

http://siddharthparasnis.com/2006-01/#menu-item-377

The page would reload scrolled down to that item.

Comment: Great answer arkigos- and you're right- the most elegant way would be to use AJAX. Alas, I don't have the expertise for that solution. Your menu-item link change worked before I started messing with it...

How did you get the 377 number? I think that's all I need to make this all work. Thank you!

Comment: It's the id of the link tag. You can sync the page up to any HTML element (as far as I know) by referencing the id of that element preceded by a hash mark '#'. This can just be tacked on to the end of any URL for the desired effect. I found the id by reading the page source.

Comment: I *just* figured that out using firebug, ha! But thanks for the reply. It works, but now my problem is the scrollbar for the entire page moves down and that makes things a bit jarring for the user!

Comment: I've not noticed this behavior except when my screen/browser window is unusually small. Unfortunately, without resorting to a pretty significant website restructuring + AJAX, I don't know that there is another solution.